# Ignite does not honor the sql limit clause?

Tags: ignite

I am working on an application with a distributed, replicated ignite cache. I need to run updates on the cache in batches with a limit. A simplified version of the code follows.

```java
IgniteCache<...> fooCache = ...;
SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery("UPDATE Foo SET bar=1 WHERE bar=2 LIMIT 1000");
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = fooCache.query(query);
long updatedCount = (Long) cursor.iterator().next().get(0);
System.out.println(updatedCount); // greater than 1000
```

Looking at the logs, there seems to be cases where the number of entries updated is greater than the limit in the query. Is that at all possible with the way that ignite distributes SQL queries? If so, how can I adjust the query or the cache configuration to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is your use case for using `UPDATE ... LIMIT ...`? I can imagine other ways to achieve similar behavior, but the exact approach would depend on the goals.

Comment: Basically, I am marking entries for later processing in batches. There is a batch size limit imposed by an external dependency in a later processing step. There are certainly other approaches I could take to enforce that limit so I can find another solution if I can't find an answer to this question.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but had no success - apparently I always get correct result from the `UPDATE` (equal to the `LIMIT`). Can you give some additional details? How often do you see values greater than `LIMIT`? What is your cluster and cache config (how many nodes are there, what is cache mode, is native or 3rd party persistence enabled, etc)?

Comment: @cambunctious Is your data concurrently updated from elsewhere? Are there other threads that are concurrently changing the data set?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We are using replicated cache mode. There are at least 2 nodes. No native or 3rd party persistence. There are concurrent updates in other threads.